# Ending a Program When a Negative Number is Read From a File

Tags: java, file

I'm working on a program that is supposed to read numbers (double) in from a file and perform some calculations on them (creating octagon objects). However, we are supposed to end the program when a negative number is read in, and I'm not sure how to do this?

The file that is being used looks like this:

```
5.0
7.5
3.26
0.0
-1.0
```

I am using a while loop to read in the file and assign the values to variables, so would I just need to add something to my while loop to end if the number is negative? Something like:

```
while(fin.hasNext()) {
    double side = fin.nextDouble();
        if(side < 0) 
            //do whatever I need to do to end the program
 }
```

Or am I totally wrong in that thinking?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: `hasNext()` returns `boolean`.

Comment: what is the reader that you are using?

Comment: Oh duh I knew that, guess I wasn't thinking. Any suggestions as to how I should do it instead?

Comment: I'm just using a Scanner named fin.

Comment: Assuming that you are iterating through your file, you should be calling some sort of `next()` method. That will return you a String object, which you can just typecast to an int or float and check if it's negative.

Comment: You actually want nextDouble() in this case...

Comment: Ok I think I've got it now. I'll update the question to make sure I'm getting it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't quite work, because `fin.hasNext()` only returns whether or not the next line is EOF (aka  there is no more text), not the contents themselves. You will need to check for a negative value inside the loop. This is done by calling `nextDouble()` and comparing it with 0, and then breaking if it isn't positive. All of this is assuming that you are using Java's Scanner class.

The code would be:

```
while (fin.hasNextDouble()) {
    double num = fin.nextDouble();

    if (num < 0.0) break;

    // do your stuff
```

Comment: So something like: while(fin.hastNext()) { double side = fin.nextDouble(); if side < 0 // do whatever I need to do to end teh program?

Comment: I would even recommend replacing hasNext() with hasNextDouble() but basically yeah.

Answer (score 1):

It would be as simple as doing

```
while(fin.nextDouble()) {

    double d = fin.nextDouble();

    if (d < 0) {

        break;
    }

    ...
}
```

Another approach to doing this would be doing

```
double d;

while(fin.hasNextDouble() && (d = fin.nextDouble()) >= 0) {

    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you need to keep the value that is read I'm assuming so you can parse it and not just discard it. While yes you could use something something like while(fin.hasNext() && (d = fin.nextDouble()) >= 0) {} I avoid it as I find it harder to read then the approach above.

Comment: Just change `hasNext()` to `hasNextDouble()` and I will delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that method existed.